# CP Asset thumbnails delivered by PHP

Tags: craft3, control-panel

When listing entries with lots of assets (and therefore thumbnails), the server slows down significantly.

I realized, that the assets all have the path:
`https://mypage.url/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/thumb&uid=a59e2c6f-1d32-4568-ab34-8655d33427d8&width=30&height=30&v=1559381105`. However, I thought they were located in the `cpresources` folder?

Is there a way to make Craft use direct links to the thumbnails instead of using PHP to deliver the images?

Answer (score 2):

Not everything in the Control Panel gets published to the `cpresources` folder, especially things like dynamically generated images (thumbnails are basically just image transforms).

> Is there a way to make Craft use direct links to the thumbnails instead of using PHP to deliver the images?

Not currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use the Imager plugin to offload thumbnail creation](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft#useforcpthumbs-bool) to [Imgix](https://www.vaersaagod.no/en/support-for-imgix-in-imager-for-craftcms). Not free, but extremely performant.